# Python Dataframe Plotting by rows

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, visualization

I am using a dataframe that has the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd place scores as the rows and the years of those scores by column.  I am trying to create a stacked bar chart in order to show the scores by year stacked by 1st, 2nd, and 3rd place. I don't know how to get it to stack properly without row names?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> df.rename(index={0: "first", 1: "second", 2: "third"}).T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]